# How to remove/replace tab activities in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I have implemented 4 tabs, each having an activity assosiated with it. Is it advisable to remove/replace those activities for better performance of app? If yes then how to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by remove/replace those activities? And what performance increase are you talking about?

Comment: I gave an answer. I don't really know if it completely answers your question or not, but if you need some more enlightenment or whatever, then just comment on my answer and I'll see if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that having 3 tabs instead of 4 will noticeably change performance. You need to have as many tabs as suits your app. In my app, I need 4 tabs because if I had 3, then the use ability would be bad, and it would be confusing to navigate.
If you want 5+ tabs, then I'd recommend doing away with the tabwidget and then implement your own custom layout (possibly a horiziontal scrollview) as is implemented in WeatherBug. Then on that custom layout, on each button or imageView or whatever is in your custom layout, you would call `setCurrentTab` in an onClick for the views.

And I have 4 tabs like this:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityTabOther.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("other").setIndicator("General",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.other))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityTabLocate.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("locate").setIndicator("Locate",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.locate))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityTabSecure.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("secure").setIndicator("Secure",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.secure))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        //If you want to remove a tab, delete everything from here down, and that's minus one tab.
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ActivityTabFriends.class);
        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("friends").setIndicator("Friends",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.findabuddy))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```